# Starting Team Foundation Build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I recently switched to TFS 2010 and I want to start using Team Foundation Build to automate the build process for my application. I need some good resources (blogs, articles, books) on this topic.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? And what do you want the blog/article/book to be about? It's not hard to set up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are after Team Foundation Build for TFS 2010, then take a look at the following chapter that I wrote for the book [Professional Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio 2010](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470484268).

[Chapter 21: Team Foundation Build.](http://media.wiley.com/product_data/excerpt/68/04704842/0470484268-3.pdf)

Otherwise the blogs that [Richard points to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2606710/starting-team-foundation-build/2606754#2606754) are an excellent resource.  Also the following book is very good for Team Foundation Build prior to TFS 2010

[Inside the Microsoft Build Engine: Using MSBuild and Team Foundation Build](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735626286)

Answer (score 1):

To install build server use the latest version of the Installation Guide for your TFS version (you should have this from the install).

TFS team blogs include the following (pulled from a `.opml` hence XML fragment):

```
<outline type="rss" title="Martin Woodward" description="" xmlUrl="http://feeds.feedburner.com/MartinWoodward" htmlUrl="http://www.woodwardweb.com/" />
<outline type="rss" title="granth's blog" description="Program Manager for Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Team Foundation Server (TFS)" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/granth/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Ozzie Rules Blogging (Charles Sterling: MS VSTS Community Lead)" description="Charles Sterling's WebLog" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/charles_sterling/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/charles_sterling/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Team Foundation's WebLog" description="Application Lifecycle Management with Visual Studio Team Foundation Server" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/team_foundation/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/team_foundation/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Version Control Server Team" description="Version Control - Team Foundation Server - Visual Studio North Carolina" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/tfsvcs/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/tfsvcs/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Jeff Beehler (VSTS Lead Pgm Mgr)" description="" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/jeffbe/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Rob Caron's Blog - A Team System Nexus" description="Developer-related topics and other stuff." xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/robcaron/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/robcaron/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="bharry's WebLog" description="Everything you want to know about Visual Studio ALM and Farming" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/bharry/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Buck Hodges (Team Foundation Server)" description="Visual Studio ALM (VSTS) - Team Foundation Server - Team Build - Web Access - Version Control - Admin & Ops" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/buckh/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Mario Rodriguez (PM TFS VCS)" description="" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/mrod/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/mrod/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="James Manning's blog" description="Team Foundation Server + PowerShell = Happiness" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/jmanning/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Michal Malecki (Version Control Client Dev)" description="" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/michalma/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/michalma/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Aaron Hallberg (Team Build: Build Automation)" description="Team Build (Build Automation) - Visual Studio North Carolina" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/aaronhallberg/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="TFS Version Control and VS Integration" description="" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/benryan/rss.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/benryan/default.aspx" />
<outline type="rss" title="Stephanie Saad's Weblog" description="" xmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/stephaniesaad/atom.xml" htmlUrl="http://blogs.msdn.com/stephaniesaad/default.aspx" />
```